# Calculating matrix elements for quarkonium decay amplitudes

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, isospin-symmetry, mesons

In [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-ph/9507326.pdf) paper (Appendix A) several decay amplitudes are calculated. How does this work?

Note that
$$
|n \bar n \rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (| u \bar u \rangle  + |d \bar d\rangle ) \\
\eta = \cos \phi |n\bar n\rangle  - \sin \phi |s \bar s \rangle 
\\
\rho = \frac{\left< 0 \left | V \right| s \bar s \right>}{\left< 0 \left | V \right| d \bar d \right>} \\
$$

I tried using isospin and Clebsch-Gordan coefficients so far, but this does not work. E.g. for $I=1$ and $\left< Q \bar Q \left| V \right| K \bar K \right>$ my calculations are:

$$ | n \bar n \rangle   = |1,0\rangle  \\ 
| K \bar K\rangle  = |d \bar s \rangle  + | \bar d s \rangle   $$
with  $$ | d \bar s \rangle  = | 1/2, -1/2\rangle  \times |0,0\rangle  = |1/2, -1/2\rangle  $$
this yields not the proper result.

Comment: The weird mixed isospin and strangeness state you are writing down is some unnormalized K-short, definitely not the $|K\bar K\rangle$ state you have on the left hand side which should contain 2 quarks and tw0 antiquarks. With a state so malformed, it would be a miracle if you got anything at all that is consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is not the prettiest notation, but, crudely, the isotriplet two- strangeful-meson state quashes its strange quarks to the vacuum, 
$$\langle0|V|K\bar{K}\rangle\rangle_{I=1} \to \rho |n\bar{n}\rangle/2, 
$$
but this is just the isotriplet quarkonium state,
$$
|Q\bar{Q}\rangle_{I=1}= |n\bar{n}\rangle,
$$
once it has been normalized: Effectively, $|Q\bar{Q}\rangle$ is   $|n\bar{n}\rangle$.

As a result, 
$$
\langle Q\bar{Q}|V|K\bar{K}\rangle_{I=1}=\rho/2 .
$$